# Subdivision problem after extruding

Tags: modeling

I am just getting started with blender so I tried to do a simple model of a building in my city.
After trying to subdivide a face, this is what I get every time I extrude the faces. How can I repair this? I can not use undo.

https://youtu.be/8MtQu9J0XI0

[image: Extruded face]

Comment: So you mean all those lines? Try to swap from face mode to vertice mode at top left corner next to edit mode... You will surely notice that there are many vertices on each edge that are making those lines because you are extruding them... Also Disolve faces will get rid of lines but not vertices, you need to dissolve or remove those vertices first

Answer (score 0):

Your model is on the right, what you want is on the left side:
[image]

How is this possible? As I have said, go to vertice mode up here:

[image]

After this you will surely see your edges like this:
[image]

You have to fix this... you can simply delete them and rebuild your topology or dissolve them/merge them like this for example:

---

Remove what you had:
[image]

and now just take all of those vertices and remove them:
[image]

fill it with F, extrude once again and your problem is gone:
[image]

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working as I thought. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/da6RPAq.gif) is what I'm talking about, not all the vertices are deleting. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You deleted some vertices but there are another ones under them... how did you actually managed to do that? I can see that few of them went away, so I recommend to you just clean it more with simply deleting them and building topology again... I really wonder how you made those vertices

Comment: I have no idea how I did this haha. I will start over again, thank you for the help!